# How does my /bin/ls -l Shellcode works with Null Bytes?

Tags: x86, nasm, shellcode

I'm trying to execute a Shellcode with execve function along with commands arguments i.e '/bin/ls -l'. What I know is that shellcode cannot work properly if it has null bytes in it.

But my shellcode has null bytes when i push -l argument into the stack and it work just fine. Why?

```
08048060 <_start>:
                                       ;Pushing /x00
8048060:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
8048062:       50                      push   eax

8048063:       68 6e 2f 6c 73          push   0x736c2f6e  ;Pushing //bin/ls
8048068:       68 2f 2f 62 69          push   0x69622f2f
804806d:       89 e3                   mov    ebx,esp
804806f:       50                      push   eax
8048070:       89 e2                   mov    edx,esp
8048072:       50                      push   eax
8048073:       68 2d 6c 00 00          push   0x6c2d    ; Pushing '-l' which has null bytes
8048078:       89 e6                   mov    esi,esp
804807a:       50                      push   eax
804807b:       56                      push   esi
804807c:       53                      push   ebx
804807d:       89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp
804807f:       b0 0b                   mov    al,0xb
8048081:       cd 80                   int    0x80
```

Answer (score 3):

Shellcodes can contains null bytes if the vector that puts them in an executable buffer allows for them.
The most known vector is a single-byte null-terminated string copy (e.g. `strcpy`), in such case a null byte will denote the end of the source string, thereby preventing the copy of the full shellcode.
However if the copy operation has a fixed length (e.g. a structured protocol) or it is not using single-byte string (e.g. utf-*) then a null byte may not abort the copy early.

Of course, if you are running your shellcode as it was a standalone program, you are skipping the copy phase altogether and no special consideration is needed.